# How to use the UndoManager to determine if document has unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm quite new to the [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org) editor and javascript in general however I have managed to achieve most of what I intended apart from the following:

I would like to enable or disable a 'save' button depending on whether there are outstanding modifications to the document and I have attempted to do this with 'change' event:

```
UndoManager.reset();

$('#save').addClass("disabled");

editor.on('change', function() {

        if (UndoManager.hasUndo()) {
            $('#save').removeClass("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $('#save').addClass("disabled");
        }

    });
```

On loading a document the 'disabled' class is removed immediately.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can show me how it should be done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Call `editor.session.getUndoManager().reset()` after loading the document
and use `isClean`, `markClean` methods on `undoManager`.

```js
var saveButton = document.getElementById("save")
var editor = ace.edit("editor")
// using input event instead of change since it's called with some timeout
editor.on("input", function() {
    saveButton.disabled = editor.session.getUndoManager().isClean()
});

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    editor.session.getUndoManager().markClean()
    saveButton.disabled = editor.session.getUndoManager().isClean()
})
```

```html
<script src="http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src/ace.js"></script>
<button id="save">save</button>
<div id="editor" style="height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well (although I had to switch the add and remove class statement - my fault). Is it possible to capture when the user has rewound back to the beginning of the undo buffer and then add the disabled class again? Either way, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the .isClean() to .hasUndo() (and reversed the add/remove statements) and now when the user rewinds to the beginning of the undo buffer the 'save' button disables. It also supports redo. Very cool.

Comment: @Wasim make sure you are using newest version of ace

Comment: I was loading new data into the editor on some events.  The undo manager operates after a delay, so I needed to put my markClean() function call inside a delay, like this: `setTimeout(function() { editor.getSession().getUndoManager().reset(); }, 700);` (reset() or markClean() both worked for me in my case)

Answer (score 9):

Your solution has a disadvantage: after saving, you are not able to undo. Most modern editors allow undo after saving.

I suggest that you record down the original text and do a comparision whenever text changes. if text equals origin, disable save button.

Comment: Simple and efficient!