# Looking for changes in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, hash, tokenize, ace-editor

I'm trying to make sure a user can't close a file without saving changes they've made using the ace editor.

I see the I can watch for an onChange event, and one possibility is to set a flag on the onChange and if a user wants to close the file, check the flag is not set, or else put them into a save work flow.

However, not sure this is the best way to do it. For example, if a user makes a change, then undoes the change, they shouldn't need to save the file.

I see Ace Editor also has a tokenizer, so I was thinking about tokenizing the editor content on initialize, and then check if the token has changed. Though I'm not sure that is really what the tokenizer is for (or what it is for).

The way I was thinking of doing it was to create a hash (md5 unless somebody else has other recommendations) and then check the hash matches a hash of the current content before closing a file. If the hashes don't match, the content has changed and the user goes into the save flow, which in the end, updates the hash.

Any thoughts on the right way of doing this with Ace?

Comment: why not just compare the "file text" from load with that of the editor at time of execution? that gives you the first half of a revert command as well...

Comment: @dandavis I figured comparing a hash would be faster than comparing the whole text, but then again, I'll have to hash the text before comparing.

Comment: hash is more work than creating a pointer or even duping a small block of ram for ascii text, and you don't need to run this function often anyway, so who cares about a few ms...

Comment: @dandavis if you put your response as an answer, I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it with help from this site:

[ACE editor change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670178/ace-editor-change-event)